# mozilla: What happens and how to remove totally firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm having the following issue
I have a chinese version of Firefox I want to remove,  aim is to install an english version of it, clean slate , and remove any references , configuration , bookmarks etc ... , to the chinese version.

I used the add/remove programs to uninstall Firefox but it did not work out, probably due to the tons of malware , this laptop has (don't ask where I got it :) )  .

I deleted manually the installation folder, as mentionned in this link -> https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/973277

I was able to remove the installation and reinstall it with an english version.

Issue is with this english version, the chinese bookmarks and all references to my old chinese version of firefox are intact , like I did not uninstall anything  ...

I read somewhere it might be related to some folders , which contains `%APPDATA%` and where they might harbor references to the old installation.

I did not find anything else except than what I mentionned above.

If you have any clues, I'm all ears.

Cheers.

Comment: What happens if you [create a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)?

Comment: aha @DavidPostill ! I did not try that ... until now :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looks like you solved it, nevermind, I'll leave this for others :P

Well, straight off I'm just going to mention that antivirus might be worth getting, if you so wish, to deal with the virus problem

To the main point:
Lets start simple, if you open up "My Computer" or "This PC" on a newer OS, then type "mozilla" in the search box, the search will likely uncover some remaining hidden files (make sure you have the hidden files box ticked in the view options at the top of windows explorer).

Do the same with "Firefox" instead of mozilla, delete what you find in both cases unless they are clearly not related to firefox.

It may be worth installing the English version after this to see if that's all that was required, otherwise its registry editing time. I'll modify this post the the required instructions should you need them.

Comment: Hey @sam3000, it is never lost. I will let you know this week on the whereabout for this pc. Cheers